# What is this QR code like thing?

Tags: pcb

I found this QR code like object on a PCB today. I tried scanning it with a QR code scanner, but I didn't get a result. What is this? If it is similar to a QR code, how do I scan it?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a "Datamatrix" barcode, not QR. You may have to go in to your barcode scanner's settings to enable datamatrix scanning.

"45506501001855200841661E" is what is encoded.

If you want to read more, you can see it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix

There are two good reasons to use Datamatrix: good data density (more characters per sq mm) and the patent is expired.

Comment: Ah, Datamatrix. I didn't have any search terms to search for this on google, I couldn't find this when I searched for 'types of barcodes'. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: The class this thing falls under is a "2D barcode" it will show up if you search for that. There are MANY kinds of barcodes.

Comment: Used for "direct part marking" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_part_marking) of PCBs and other components.